# Missing Vite Manifest File after deployment

Tags: laravel, hosting, vite, laravel-jetstream

I have deployed my laravel project using hostinger. I've encounter a problem where there is Missing Vite Manifest File deploy at line

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

How do i solve this?
I saw answers recommending on stack

```
npm run dev/npm install/ npm run build
```

I tried running them before uploading the files to the server, but they did not work. Is there ant other way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it locally, you need to remove `/public/build` from `.gitignore` otherwise it will never upload if you add it on `.gitignore`.

Another way, you could add `npm run build`, on your deploy script

Comment: I tried that too, but it does not work. This is the link https://eurofinsmy.net/register

Comment: How do i run npm run build on a deploy script? I couldnt find any terminal on the hosting website hostinger

Comment: @ggcode could you confirm if there is `build` folder on server, if not, could be git cache issue.

Comment: Yes, there is a ```build``` folder under ```public_html```

Comment: and still there isn't manifest.json inside build folder?

Comment: there is a manifest,json inside, this is the code of the file                                             
```{
  "resources/js/app.js": {
    "file": "assets/app.7cafe3db.js",
    "src": "resources/js/app.js",
    "isEntry": true
  },
  "resources/css/app.css": {
    "file": "assets/app.0e1d3a96.css",
    "src": "resources/css/app.css",
    "isEntry": true
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the exact error you are receiving?

Comment: Vite manifest not found at: /home/u765133174/domains/eurofinsmy.net/eurotracks/public/build/manifest.json. It didnt appear on that website just now because i deleted the line but forget to put it back when asking.

Comment: I also dont know hwo to run a npm run build on the deploy script, is it through manifest.json?

Answer (score 0):

when you are pushing to production remove **/public/build** from .gitignore of course after running **npm run build** locally.